# Make form with css or canvas

Tags: image, css, canvas

I wonder if it is possible to create the image below, using css or canvas? It seems possible but do not have the ways to accomplish such a feat.

[image: Fence-Over]

Grateful for the time spent.

**Edit {SOLVED}**

With the help of friend @ apaul34208, could do as follows:
http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/CcDG7/

```
#hexagon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

#hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#hexagon

Answer (score 3):

You can use canvas this way:

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/5qE3t/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="demo" width=90 height=120></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),  /// get canvas element
    w = demo.width,               /// cache dimensions
    h = demo.height,
    cw = w * 0.5;                 /// center hori.

ctx.beginPath();                  /// start path
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);                 /// plot shape
ctx.lineTo(w, 0);
ctx.lineTo(w, h - cw * 0.8);
ctx.lineTo(cw, h);
ctx.lineTo(0, h - cw * 0.8);
ctx.closePath()                   /// closes and ends last line
ctx.fillStyle ='#f55641';
ctx.fill();                       /// fill shape
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#square {
   width: 90px; 
   height: 85px; 
   background: #f55641; 
}
#triangle { 
   width: 0; 
   height: 0;
   border-top: 35px solid #f55641;
   border-left: 45px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 45px solid transparent; 
}

<div id="square"></div>
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: would you mind creating a Demo, or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us, and perhaps elaborating on your answer a little bit?